# How and where to make global function file in jsp sevlet web application

Tags: java, object-oriented, functional-programming, jsp

I am making a website in Servlet&JSP. I am looking for good way to make a specific function file from where I can call and declare my common functions. If I made a java file function. Java, so is it required to include it, in every page where I want that or there is any specific way to do this kind of  global stuff.

Comment: Please remove the nonsense second paragraph and report what you have tried so far.

Comment: For the sake of everyone working on the codebase in which you want to do this. Please keep this sort of logic out of JSP. It's a much better idea to place all of your business logic in Java classes and only expose very simple objects in JSP, making it just the presentation layer.

Comment: thanks... actually i just started working in jsp/servlet. so can you please suggest me better way to build web applications or can you share several pre-build application with me which you made so far .... show that i can lean from them.